# Port forward from router to pc with openvpn

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, kubuntu

so I want to port forward from my router to my computer which is using openvpn. The computer is running Kubuntu, before I did the same thing with windows, installed the openvpn client and ran it, and I could port forward to the computer, however in linux it doesn't seem as straight forward.

NETSTAT-

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.8.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.138      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eno1
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eno1
10.0.0.138      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eno1
10.8.8.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
45.125.247.195  10.0.0.138      255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eno1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eno1
```

My routers address is 10.0.0.138. Thanks!

Comment: is that your Home Network?